# Im trying to make a text based game that looks like a PC terminal, i cant find a way to tell the user if they use a wrong sentence

Tags: java

```
//Code up
if (userinput.contains(help)) {
//Go on with the game
}
else {
System.out.println("Im sorry , couldnt understand that"); //here is where i want to go back up and 
                                                            repeat the command 
}
```

I tried almost everything a beginner would know and nothing , do while loops not working in my case (maybe you can find a way) , if i let the if like that the game closes if  you get the wrong answer (something out of conttext) , some help would be great! Thx :D

Comment: Maybe you can use the `continue`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'Recursive' function (a function that calls itself).

So in this case, you could do something like:

```js
public void getAndParseInput(){
  String userInput = getUserInput() // Use whatever you're using to get input
  if(userInput.contains(help)){ 
    // If the user input contains whatever the help is (note: if you're looking for the specific word help, it needs to be in speech marks - "help").
    continueWithGame...
  }else{
    System.out.println("Im sorry , couldnt understand that");
    this.getAndParseInput();
  }
}
```

Comment: Weird , doesn't work , can you please be a bit more specific on how i use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that code inside a while loop and establish an exit condition.

```
boolean endGame = false;

/* Here read userinput */

While(!endGame) {
  if (userinput.contains(help)) {
    //Go on with the game
  } else if(userinput.contains("quit"){
    endGame = true;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Im sorry , couldnt understand that"); //here is where i want to go back up and 
                                                            repeat the command 
  }

  /* Here read userinput */

}
```

Comment: The result in the console is a spam , runs the loop over and over

Comment: You have to add your code where it says `/* Here read userinput */` which is in two places. By the way nothing to do with spam, I don't see this sent to anyone, in any case you have an infinite loop. Which you won't if you add your code.

Answer (score 0):

The Below code is similar to your code,reuse the code with appropriate changes as you required.

The code works as below.

 1. Scans the input from the console
 2. Compares the scanned input with the String "help"
 3. If scanned input matches with help, then continue with the execution
 4. Otherwise, if the user wants to continue then he can press the
    letter 'C' and continues with the execution.
 5. If user doesn't press 'C', then the control breaks the while loop
    and comes out of the execution

```
    public void executeGame() {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         String help = "help";
         while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter the input for execution");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.contains(help)){
               System.out.println("Continue execution");
            } else {
               System.out.println("Sorry Wrong input.. Would you like to continue press C");
               input = scanner.nextLine();
               if (input.equals("C")){
                  continue;
               } else {
                  System.out.println("Sorry wrong input :"+input);
                  System.out.println("Hence Existing....");
                  System.exit(0);
               }
          }
      }
    }
```